# JavaScript Looping Through Array, Combining After

Tags: javascript

I get a string of data back that is seperata by semi colons. Here is an example: 
apple;orange;lemon).

I am trying to strip out the semi colons and turn the string into an array, so I can access each item individually. Then, I am trying to join them back together and print them out on the screen separated by a "/". The problem is that it is not working.

```
var planArray = associatedAction.split(";")
for(var i=0; i < planArray.length; i++) {
   var seperatedActionPlan = planArray[i];       
}
```

Also, I would like to put the final output into a variable, so I can print out just that variable on the page.

Please help!

**EDIT!**

One thing I forgot to mentioned, is that when the string prints out, I want the values to be separated. So as an example I want the final print out to be `<a href="#">Apple</a>/<a href="#">Orange</a>/<a href="#">Lemon</a>`

Comment: you mark answer that is not solution your question.you said :  I want the final print out to be `<a href="#">Apple</a>/<a href="#">Orange</a>/<a href="#">Lemon</a>` but marked answer dont it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
          var associatedAction = "a;b;c;d";
          var planArray = associatedAction.split(";")
          var seperatedActionPlan = '';

          for (var i = 0; i < planArray.length; i++) {
               if (i < planArray.length - 1) {                
                  seperatedActionPlan =  
                        seperatedActionPlan.concat(planArray[i] + "/");                
        }
        else {
            seperatedActionPlan = seperatedActionPlan.concat(planArray[i]);
        }           
    }

    alert(seperatedActionPlan);

    </script>
```

Comment: this is perfect, but the final string is there anyway to print them out separately. I would like each item from the array to be a separate link that is divided by a "/". Please see my edit.

Comment: Nevermind, I was missing something obvious. Great answer, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
var seperatedActionPlan = planArray.join("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let seperatedActionPlan = associatedAction.split(";").join("/"));
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var associatedAction = "apple;orange;lemon";
            var planArray = associatedAction.split(";")
            for(var i = 0; i < planArray.length; i++ ) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                var txt = document.createTextNode("/");
                a.href = "#";
                a.innerHTML = planArray[i];
                document.body.appendChild(a); 
                if (i != planArray.length - 1)
                    a.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',"/"); 
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Алина Заморская , Check my Answer!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
var planArray = associatedAction.split(";"),
    seperatedActionPlan;

for(var i=0; i < planArray.length; i++) {
    // ... do what you need
}

seperatedActionPlan = planArray.join('/');

// print out seperatedActionPlan
```

or if you don't do anything to the array except splitting and joining with `/` just use

```
var seperatedActionPlan = associatedAction.replace(';', '/');
// print out seperatedActionPlan
```